# Multi Client Dropbox Like Service on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, file-sharing, dropbox

We currently have around 15 dropbox accounts which multiple clients use to send files to our office.  This is extremely unmanageable from an administrative standpoint and also very inefficient from a productivity standpoint.

We have moved our offsite backup structure to AWS and am trying to figure out a way to streamline this workflow on AWS.  Essentially I would like to have isolated storage buckets that I can easily give my users access to and then send clients authentication and access to (preferably without a local client).

Would S3 be the way to go about this (if so how) or is there another aws service that is better suited ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be looking for http://aws.amazon.com/zocalo/

> Amazon Zocalo is a fully managed, secure enterprise storage and sharing service with strong administrative controls and feedback capabilities that improve user productivity.
>
> Users can comment on files, send them to others for feedback, and upload new versions without having to resort to emailing multiple versions of their files as attachments. Users can take advantage of these capabilities wherever they are, using the device of their choice, including PCs, Macs, tablets and phones. Amazon Zocalo offers IT administrators the option of integrating with existing corporate directories, flexible sharing policies, audit logs, and control of the location where data is stored. Customers can get started using Amazon Zocalo with a 30-day free trial providing 200 GB of storage per user for up to 50 users.

Comment: Thank you very much this is exactly what I am looking for.  I love AWS but theres is so much it can be overwhelming !  Have a great day